# Nested if-else statement, only the first criteria is being tested

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, statistics

I have a dataset, "cipe", and am trying to create a new variable, "case", if any of the following criteria "htn, "sle", "apls", "diabetes", "ckd" are met

The code I am using is:

```
cipe <- mutate(cipe, case == ifelse(htn == 1, "1",
                                ifelse(sle == 1, "1",
                                       ifelse(apls == 1, "1",
                                              ifelse(diabetes == 1, "1",
                                                     ifelse(ckd == 1, "1", "0"))))))
```

My dataset has ~840k observations so it is not feasible to post, but when i run this code the number of "1"s in the new "case" variable is exactly equal to the number of "1"s in "htn", (should be much higher), so the other tests are not being assessed. Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: Do you need `df$case <- rowSums(cipe[c('htn', 'sle', 'apls', 'diabetes', 'ckd')])` ?

Comment: Are you actually using `case == ifelse(…` this should be `case = ifelse(` otherwise it will error unless you have `case` already defined somewhere. Other than that the function looks like it should work as intended. You could provide a simple example or your data using `dput(dplyr::sample_n(cipe,15))`

Answer (score 0):

We can subset the columns of the dataset 'cipe', create a logical matrix by comparing with 1, use `rowSums` check if it is greater than 0, convert the logical to binary with `+` or `as.integer`

```
+(rowSums(cipe[c('sle', 'apls', 'diabetes', 'ckd')] == 1) > 0)
```

---

Or another option is `Reduce` with `|`

```
+(Reduce(`|`, lapply(cipe[c('sle', 'apls', 'diabetes', 'ckd')], `==`, 1)))
```